# How to find which folder a file belongs to using Java?

Tags: java, file-io

When I execute the following code:

```
File f = getFile();
String absPath = f.getAbsolutePath()

System.out.println(absPath);
```

I get the following print out:

> C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\test\file.txt

But that's not what I want! I want the absolute path **leading up** to `file.txt`, i.e.:

> C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\test\

I'm trying to figure out how to use the Java File I/O API to accomplish this but I can't seem to find anything that is a match for what I'm looking for.  Thanks for any nudges in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look here: [File#getParentFile()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParentFile%28%29)

Comment: This was the first right answer! I saw your deleted comment!! haha! ;)

Comment: I would, if google wouldn't bring it to the first search hit, everytime I search for java-docs.

Comment: type "6" (or even "7") after the class. The top result is for 1.4.2 because people still give links to it.

Comment: I changed th link. By the way I think 7 is still to new :-)

Comment: *"I think 7 is still to new "*  The v. 7 docs has everything the 6 docs have, as well as `@since` and `@deprecated` flags.  The first warns you of new functionality that might not be in your target JRE.  The latter warns of methods that you are using at the moment, which might be *about to be deprecated* come the next version.  As such, it would pay to start changing the code right now, in anticipation.  In short, there is ***no*** good reason for linking to anything but the latest docs that are available (at Oracle, not the dev. site).

Answer (score 2):

The `getParentFile()` method of File is your friend here.